# Cannot connect sparklyr to Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to connect sparklyr to Spark by 
`library("sparklyr")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")`

But I get

```
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  :    sparklyr does not currently support Spark version: 2.2.0`
```

I have installed and then uninstalled Spark 2.2.0 to change it to 2.0.2, but it seems that I haven't property done it.

If I call

`sc <- spark_connect(master = "local:7077")`

I get

```
Error in shell_connection(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, app_name = app_name,


Failed to connect to Spark (SPARK_HOME is not set).
```

Once I run `echo $SPARK_HOME` get `/root/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7`

Any recommendations for the noob?

Comment: Yes I did set it.

Comment: where you able to solve this? i'm getting the same error...